# Load Image from parse to Collection View Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I would like to get some advices how to solve a problem. I would like to load images stored on Parse Server into my collection View, I am using the following code :

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    //var my_array:[String] = []
    //var my_array: [String] = [String]()
    var imageResources : Array<UIImage> = []
    //var query = PFQuery(className: "User")
    var query2 = PFQuery(className: "User")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //my_array = ["montagne.jpeg","montagne.jpeg","montagne.jpeg","montagne.jpeg","montagne.jpeg","montagne.jpeg","montagne.jpeg","montagne.jpeg","montagne.jpeg","montagne.jpeg","montagne.jpeg","montagne.jpeg","montagne.jpeg","montagne.jpeg"]

        query2.findObjectsInBackground{ (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                print("OK")

                for object in objects! {
                    print("IN FOR")
                    let thumbNail = object["image"] as! PFFile
                    thumbNail.getDataInBackground({
                        (imageData: Data?, error: Error?) -> Void in
                        if (error == nil) {
                            print("IN SECOND IF")
                            let image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                            self.imageResources.append(image!)
                            //let size = self.imageResources.count
                            //print(size)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }

        //query.findObjectsInBackground{ (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
          //  if error == nil {
          //          for object in objects! {
          //              self.my_array.append(object.object(forKey: "image") as! String)

                  //  }
           // }
        }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageResources.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.ImageView?.image = imageResources[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }
}
```

I don't have any error when I run my App, however i don't get the images on my App inside the Collection View. The image are in my Parse Server : [Parser Server Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oku6T.png)

I just figured out that inside this code, the print `print("IN FOR")` doesn't print, so I supposed there is something wrong here and thats why my App doesnt load anything :

```
query2.findObjectsInBackground{ (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                print("OK")

                for object in objects! {
                    print("IN FOR")
                    let thumbNail = object["image"] as! PFFile
                    thumbNail.getDataInBackground({
                        (imageData: Data?, error: Error?) -> Void in
                        if (error == nil) {
                            print("IN SECOND IF")
                            let image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                            self.imageResources.append(image!)
                            //let size = self.imageResources.count
                            //print(size)
                        }
                    })
                }
```

But When I use fix images inside my program and that I store in an Array (the code in comment), I can see those images in my collection view ...
Could someone help me to fix this problem ? Thanks a million.

Jordy.

Comment: try to reload collection view after data come , try to take outlet for your collection view and do that collectionview.realodData() after for loop.

Comment: yes , that happen to me , try to clean project , or write     @IBOutlet var outletOfCollectionView: UICollectionView! and then attach it with collection view control

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, I got the same things, I think it's like there is a problem with the loop because it doesn't go inside the for loop ... when I want to print (print("IN FOR")) it doesnt appear in the console ..

Comment: print("OK") appear ?

Comment: Yes print("OK") appear but not the rest, like it doesnt go inside :(

Comment: so there is no  objects may be wrong in your query2

Comment: My column in parse is a File but I put "query2.findObjectsInBackground{ (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?)" PFObject, but it doesnt like if i change PFObject by PPFILE

Comment: I am sorry I did not use Parse before , but i searched how to get columns from Parse and i found that after create query use this methods please ty it query.whereKey(, equalTo:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The User class is a built-in class of Parse and internally is named `_User` (with an underscore), so your query should look like this:

```
var query2 = PFQuery(className: "_User")
```

or, more compact:

```
var query2 = PFUser.query()
```

**Edit**

After fetching the users and their images, you have to reload the collection view to make it aware of the new data; and since you are on a background queue when this happens, you have to dispatch to the main queue to do so:

```
for object in objects! {
  // ...
}
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

*However*, I don't see a `UICollectionView` in your code; you only implement the delegate and datasource protocols. You better should just subclass `UICollectionViewController` instead of `UIViewController`.

Comment: Thank you, my for loop is now working but it doesnt display the image, do I have to specify the name of the column in the user classname ? because i think i am doing that here : let thumbNail = object["image"] as! PFFile

Comment: Also consider using ParseUI to use PFImageViews with built in pffile image downloading + placeholder image support, it may make things a bit easier.